# Encountering NumberFormatException

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I am trying to convert a string to a double but get a NumberFormatException.

Here is my code:

```
String x = "";
// String ary[]=new String[10];
while (finalstr.charAt(stpr) != ' ') {
    // System.out.print(finalstr.charAt(stpr));
    Character c = new Character(finalstr.charAt(stpr));

    String s = c.toString(c);
    ary[i] = s;
    x = x + ary[i];
    i++;

    stpr++;
    // first++;
}
// System.out.print(x);
String yo = x;
// System.out.print(yo); //it prints well
// double d = Double.valueOf(yo.trim()).doubleValue();
double doubleprim = Double.parseDouble(yo);
System.out.print(doubleprim);
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share the Error StackTrace and try printing the values before converting to Number. Please share the value of yo before Type Casting. double doubleprim = Double.parseDouble(yo);

Comment: See here for an example of posting an SSCCE - http://sscce.org/.

Comment: This code is not complete. We need to see the contents of `finalstr` in order to tell what is wrong.

Comment: The exception message will give you details on what is wrong. Only the strings that correspond to a proper double value can be parsed successfully. It can be ok to give a message to user if parse exception occurs.

Comment: actually after parsing data from a webpage i try to add it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `Double.valueOf(yo.trim()).doubleValue();`

Comment: what value is yo as a String? I made a String with a value of "2502342.53" and did 

double d = Double.valueOf(num.trim()).doubleValue();

and it worked

Comment: actually i am parsing data from a webpage ..i am new in java so...value of yo=101.00

Answer (score 0):

Oh crap such an ugly code! However, if I get it correctly you are trying to construct string of all characters in `finalstr` until an interval is encountered.

Use this code:

```
String [] splits = finalstr.split(" ");
double doubleprim = Double.parseDouble(splits[0]);
```

From then on if you get th eNumberFormat exception, it is due to wrong string value, not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this . It Worked for me :

```
               CharSequence cs = amount.getText();
                if(cs!=null && cs.length()>0)
                {
                double pro = Double.parseDouble(cs.toString());
                }
```

here as you can see amount is an edittext which i am using in android.